# tm_text produces duplicate text in tmap

Tags: r, label, tmap

I'm trying to do a map using library `tmap` and [this dataset](https://github.com/andremenegatti/cagedExplorer/blob/master/data/polygons_regioes_adm_sp.rda).

Following [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56780268/adding-text-labels-to-tmap-plot), I'm using the following simple code:

```
library(tmap)
library(geobr)
library(sf)

rg = st_as_sf(polygons_regioes_adm_sp)

tm_shape(rg) + 
  tm_polygons("regiao_administrativa",
              legend.show = F) +
  tm_text("regiao_administrativa", size = 1/2)
```

That yields the following map with overlapping DUPLICATE text. I tried insert `remove.overlap = TRUE` inside `tm_text` but this doesn't worked better.

[image]

Furthermore i'm getting the following message:

```
old-style crs object detected; please recreate object with a recent sf::st_crs()
```

In this context, How I get a map without duplicate text ?

Comment: Hi @Marcos Junio, please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that we can help you in the best way. Thanks

Comment: Hi @lovalery , thanks for the feedback. I provided a link that gives access to the data I used, in addition I provided the simple code that I ran to get the figure. This is already a reproducible example. Anyone who downloads the data can easily run my example.

Comment: Hi @ Marcos Junio. O.K. sorry. Actually I'm not used to work with `.rda` files. Anyway, the main thing is that I finally managed to read your file. So, please find my answer to your problem below. If it is OK, please consider marking this answer as "accepted" and/or upvoted. If not, please tell me what is wrong. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code to display the map with the `tmap` library is fine. The problem is that the `sf` object `polygons_regioes_adm_sp` has a mixture of `POLYGON` and `MULTIPOLYGON`. So, you just need to simplify the `sf` object by running the `st_cast()` function.

As for the projection problem, you just need to specify the EPSG code to assign a recent form of the `CRS` to the `sf` object (NB: as for the warning message - cf.below - do not worry, it is fine)

So, please find below the code to display correctly the names of the administrative regions.

```r
library(tmap)
library(sf)
library(dplyr) # please, do not forget to load this library


rg <- polygons_regioes_adm_sp %>% 
  st_set_crs(4674) %>% 
  st_cast()
#> old-style crs object detected; please recreate object with a recent sf::st_crs()
#> Warning: st_crs<- : replacing crs does not reproject data; use st_transform for
#> that

tm_shape(rg) + 
  tm_polygons("regiao_administrativa",
              legend.show = F) +
  tm_text("regiao_administrativa", size = 1/2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @lovarery I hadn't noticed that detail in the data. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Marcos Junio. You're welcome. Glad I could help you. I wish you the best in your work. Cheers.