# Adding names on map using tmap/tmaptools

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sf, tmap

I have made a map using the cited packages and code. However, I would like to add names or country codes on top of each country like in picture two. Is this possible?

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)

options(scipen = 999)

data <- read_excel("Datakart.xlsx")

EU <- st_read("NUTS_RG_20M_2021_3035.shp", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

EU_and_data <- inner_join(EU, data)

euro <- c(2377294, 1313597, 7453440, 5628510)

tm_shape(EU_and_data, bbox = euro) +
  tm_polygons("2015-2019", id = "CNTR_ID", palette = "Blues", style = "cont")
```

Data:

```
structure(list(NUTS_ID = c("AT", "DK", "FI", "FR", "LU", "DE"
), `2010-2014` = c(0.3635, 0.9272, 0.5081, 0.8051, 0.8051, 0.78
), ...3 = c("***", "**", "***", "***", "***", "***"), `2015-2019` = c(0.6019, 
0.8196, 0.2917, 0.757, 0.757, 0.849), ...5 = c("***", "***", 
"*", "***", "***", "***"), STUSPS = c("NY", "NJ", "PA", "FL", 
"GA", "NC"), `2010 - 2014` = c(0.2941, 0.3832, 0.2895, 0.2835, 
0.3128, 0.2557), ...8 = c("***", "***", "***", "***", "***", 
"***"), `2015 - 2019` = c(0.1821, 0.2473, 0.24, 0.313, 0.4137, 
0.366), ...10 = c("***", "***", "***", "***", "***", "***")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

[image: Map]

[image: Map with country codes]

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: Consider adding a tm_text() call to your plot, like over here:  [Adding text labels to tmap plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56780268/adding-text-labels-to-tmap-plot)